# displaying 16bit unsigned integers in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like a simple way of achieving this, but seem to be bjorking the parameters to [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml).  I have an `std::vector<uint16_t> depth_buffer` that, on a frame-by-frame basis has depth measurements coming from a kinect.  There are exactly 640 x 480 of them, one depth measurement per pixel.  If the world went my way, the call should be

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE16, 640, 480, 0, GL_LUMINANCE16, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, depth_buffer.data());
```

Where *internalFormat* (third parameter) is `GL_LUMINANCE16` because they are 16 bit unsigned integers, and *format* is the same because that is exactly how the data is coming in.  The *type* parameter should be `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`...because these are shorts and not bytes.

Surprisingly, if I change it to be

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE16, 640, 480, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, depth_buffer.data());
```

where *internalFormat* is still `GL_LUMINANCE16`, *format* is just `GL_LUMINANCE` without the `16`, and *type* is `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, then I get **something**.  Things are clearly being skipped, but just changing to `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` doesn't cut it.

Depending on which documentation you read, *format* (the second `GL_LUMINANCE`) may or may not allow the `16` after it (anybody know why? experimentation seems to confirm this).  But my chief concern here is why `GL_UNSIGNED_**SHORT**` seems to be invalid (either all black or all white) depending on the *internalFormat* -- *format* combination.

I've tried an obscene amount of combinations here, and am looking for the **right** approach.  Anybody have some advice for achieving this?  I'm not opposed to using fbo's, but would really like to avoid it if possible...since it definitely should be doable.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't bother with `GL_LUMINANCE`, it's an obsolete feature from old versions of OpenGL (no, seriously, *don't use it*).  In a modern setting, you would use:

- Internal format `GL_R16`.  All this means is "one channel, 16 bits, normalized".
- Format `GL_RED`.  (Formats are not sized, so `GL_LUMINANCE16` is illegal here, and `GL_R16` is also illegal.)
- Type `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

Comment: Hmmmm. What you have suggested makes sense in theory, and your *format* agrees with datenwolf's response.  Using those parameters, though, gives me all black :/  Changing to `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` gives the identical skipping pattern as before, only now everything is red.  Which makes sense?  I did some toying around with `GL_R16UI` and some others, but no dice there either.  Any other thoughts?  Regardless, thanks for the response and tip about `GL_LUMINANCE` :)

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum value in the texture?  Is it possible that it's not black, but just really dark?

Comment: hmmm you are definitely on to something here.  It should be `min=0` and `max=65535` since these are ushorts.  I inverted the data to be `depth[i] = 65535 - depth[i]` and get something seemingly legitimate, though very very red in nature ;)  I thought maybe changing `glDepthRange` to be `0 - 65535` could fix it, but that wasn't any help.  Should I be trying to find a way to map things to 0-1 with GL?  I really don't want to modify the depth data itself, since that is used later for the actual project ;)

Comment: I was about to answer, but to be honest, it sounds like you are not reading any documentation, but relying on function and constant names.  **Please** read the docs.  For example, in the Kinect documentation, it will explain what it puts in the depth buffer (freenect gives physical mm or raw 11-bit data, but never normalized 16-bit data).  The OpenGL documentation explains that `glDepthRange()` changes the depth output of the rasterizer.  And the `glTexImage2D()` documentation explains which formats and types are permissible or not permissible. I know these things because I read the docs.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel I was wasting your time. I have been working on this for about 4 days before asking a question. I use 11-bit mode, but this gets padded to 16 by libfreenect (as does 10bit). 65535 is possible (indicates bad measurements e.g. lost packet). 0 is given for out of range. In any case, you have given me enough. I'll keep tinkering with it. `glDepthRange()` was an oversight, mainly out of desperation x0. Please note that I specifically cited the documentation, and asked why *format* could not have 16. Anyway, thank you for helping me get things in a forward direction, Dietrich.

Answer (score 2):

The (second) *format* parameter is only for telling *what* is contained in the data, not how it's laid out. Therefore *GL_LUMINANCE16* is an invalid token to pass to the *format* parameter (it's allowed only for the *internalformat* parameter).

The layout from which the data shall be unpacked is controlled by the *type* parameter to glTexImage *and* the pixel store settings for unpacking set with *glPixelStorei* for the *GL_UNPACK_…* parameters. Most likely your "skipping" is due to mismatched pixel store unpack parameters.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense for the *format* parameter in some senses.    Indeed, the skipping comes from me telling it to use bytes when they are shorts.